# python iterate nested classes for module

Tags: python

I am trying to create a module that wraps all classes, and use them somewhere else.

```py
class Mixins:
    class B:
        pass

    class C:
        pass


b = Mixins.B()
print(Mixins.__all_subclasses__())
# [Mixins.B, Mixins.C]
```

I mean, I can stack all subclasses in a list after I created one, but not elegant.
is there an instinctive built-in for me to do this? python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `inspect` module

```
import inspect


class Mixins:
    class B:
        pass

    class C:
        pass


print(inspect.getmembers(Mixins, lambda x: inspect.isclass(x)))
# [('B', <class '__main__.Mixins.B'>), ('C', <class '__main__.Mixins.C'>), ('__class__', <class 'type'>)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by subclassing the `Mixin` class directly and then accessing the `__subclasses__` method on the Mixin class

```
class Mixin:
    pass


class B(Mixin):
    pass


class C(Mixin):
    pass


print(Mixin.__subclasses__())
```

which prints

```
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>]
```

any class that inherits from `Mixin` is automatically available in `__subclasses__` and you don't have to manually maintain the list of "Known" instances.